# Firefox addon "RequirementError: The option "url" is invalid." when making a http request

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, httprequest, firefox-addon-sdk

This is addon code which sets up the `Request` but I dont see whats wrong here?

```
var queryString = "{\"url\":\"www.google.com\",\"method\":\"0\"}";
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var query = JSON.parse(queryString);

console.log(query);
console.log(query.url);

var req = Request({
    url: query.url,
    onComplete: function (response) {

        for (var headerName in response.headers) {
            console.log(headerName + " : " + response.headers[headerName]);
        }
    }
});
```

Produces following output:

```
console.log: MyApp: {"url":"www.google.com","method":"0"}
console.log: MyApp: www.google.com
console.error: MyApp: 
  Message: RequirementError: The option "url" is invalid.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an absolute URL. Add a scheme to it. `http://` or `https://`.